# Smarter ways to use TableAdapter with base-class, interface or partial class

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, tableadapter

C# ADO.Net TableAdapter objects do not implement an interface or a base class (other than Component).

Has anyone used TableAdapter in an application of the (GoF) Template pattern?

Update:
I would like to solve the problem described here: 
[Help to improve a migration program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834790/help-to-improve-a-migration-program)
by using the Template Pattern (GoF), 
Adapter Pattern (GoF) or other nice pattern.

Comment: Could you give us an example of what you want to do? It's not obvious what it would mean to 'use TableAdapter in a Template-like pattern.' (The canonical Gang of Four template method pattern, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern?)

Comment: @Jeff Sternal: You are right. Updated description

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TableAdapters do not have concrete base class or interface. But the MS guys are smart enough to leave partial. So you can play with the TableAdapter with the partial class. We ran into similar problem where we wanted to write generic code that can address all table-adapters in the data-model. we did it as following.

1.) **Defined an interface ITableAdapter**

```
public interface ITableAdapter<TDataTable> : IDisposable
    where TDataTable : DataTable
{
    void AttachTransaction(SqlTransaction _transaction);
    SqlTransaction CreateTransaction();

    int Update(TDataTable _dataTable);

    TDataTable GetData();
    TDataTable GetById(int Id);
}
```

2.) Later we created partial classes for each table-adapter in the project and **implemented this interface** for them.

```
public partial class UsersTableAdapter : ITableAdapter<FileParkDataSet.UsersDataTable>
{
    #region ITableAdapter<UsersDataTable> Members

    public void AttachTransaction(SqlTransaction _transaction)
    {
        if (this.Adapter == null)
            this.InitAdapter();

        this.Adapter.InsertCommand.Transaction = _transaction;
        this.Adapter.UpdateCommand.Transaction = _transaction;
        this.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Transaction = _transaction;

        foreach (var _cmd in this.CommandCollection)
        {
            _cmd.Transaction = _transaction;
        }
    }

    public SqlTransaction CreateTransaction()
    {
        if (this.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            this.Connection.Close();
        this.Connection.Open();

        return this.Connection.BeginTransaction();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Now you can program against ITableAdapter.

Comment: Hey, it's partial? That's great!

Comment: Yeah - I cam imagine your joy. We struggled a lot to find a way around to work this out. And finally we found TableAdapters to be partial.

Comment: @this.__curious_geek: Nice! +1

Comment: Can you explain exactly how you would use the generic FileParkDataSet.UsersDataTable in the adapter?

Comment: It might be worth noting that Microsoft intended for TableAdapters to participate in a transaction by being [used inside a TransactionScope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/save-data-by-using-a-transaction?view=vs-2019) rather than specifically enrolling each tableadapter in a connection specific database transaction

Answer (score 1):

Like much of the BCL, as you don't have access to the internals, you'll need to define your own class hierarchy and make references to the BCL classes less directly.

Something like the [Adapter pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/patterns/patternadapter.aspx) might suit your needs: use this to "wrap" the TableAdapter in something that you can then use as a template.

Comment: Am I the only one who wishes someone had been awake at Microsoft and just made ITableAdaptor a thing, so that we don't have to adaptor the adaptor.  If someone adapts my adapted adapter, I may have to plotz.